# ApplicationEvents claims my event wasn't fired, when called via TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, events, groovy, spock

I have a spring boot RestController, which calls a Service, which fires a custom ApplicationEvent.

When testing the service, the test is green - the fired event is correctly recognized.

However, when I'm adding a test that tests both controller and service via the HTTP interface, the test is red - the fired event isn't recognized. When debugging, I can see that SomeService.foo() *is* called. Then why does the test fail?

I'm aware that the structure of theses tests might not be ideal. This is a reduced example, the real application already has lots of these "let's test all the layers together" tests and I kind of have to stick to this structure for now.

Versions: spring-boot 3.1.4, Spock 2.4-M1-groovy-4.0

These are controller, service and event:

```java
package org.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeController {
    private final SomeService service;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void foo() {
        service.foo();
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeService {
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void foo() {
        publisher.publishEvent(new SomeEvent(this));
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

public class SomeEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    public SomeEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}
```

And these are the spock tests:

```java
package org.example

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEvents
import org.springframework.test.context.event.RecordApplicationEvents
import spock.lang.Specification

@RecordApplicationEvents
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class SomeControllerTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationEvents events;

    @LocalServerPort
    int port

    TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate()

    def "calling / fires an event"() {
        given:
        String url = sprintf("http://localhost:${port}/")

        when:
        ResponseEntity<Void> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, null, Void.class)

        then:
        response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK

        and:
        events.stream(SomeEvent.class).count() == 1
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEvents
import org.springframework.test.context.event.RecordApplicationEvents
import spock.lang.Specification

@RecordApplicationEvents
@SpringBootTest
class SomeServiceTest extends Specification {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationEvents events;

    @Autowired
    SomeService uut;

    def "some service fires some event"() {
        when:
        uut.foo()

        then:
        events.stream(SomeEvent.class).count() == 1
    }
}
```

This is the test failure:

```
Condition not satisfied:

events.stream(SomeEvent.class).count() == 1
|      |                |      |       |
|      |                |      0       false
|      |                class org.example.SomeEvent
|      <java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@644e6a8e val$mapper=inaccessible this$0=inaccessible sourceStage=inaccessible previousStage=inaccessible sourceOrOpFlags=inaccessible nextStage=inaccessible depth=inaccessible combinedFlags=inaccessible sourceSpliterator=inaccessible sourceSupplier=inaccessible linkedOrConsumed=inaccessible sourceAnyStateful=inaccessible sourceCloseAction=inaccessible parallel=inaccessible>
Current ApplicationEvents

    at org.example.SomeControllerTest.calling / fires an event(SomeControllerTest.groovy:35)
```